# SQL - Using a join on a column with multiple values in cells

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables I am trying to join. One table has a column with IDs in it, and I am trying to do a left join to a different table that has the same IDs in it, although the second table could contain more than one ID per cell. For example, if my first table has an ID value of `123`, and the second table has an ID value of `123;724;823`, is there any way to get it to join the two rows?

Answer (score 0):

You tried in query designer? Is very easy to make joins there.

*SELECT column_names
  FROM table-name1 LEFT JOIN table-name2 
    ON ID_column-name1 = ID_Column-name2
 WHERE condition X,Y,Z*

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
(
    select '123' as id
    union select '124'
) as t1
left join 
(
    select '123;001;002' as id
    union select '001;123;002'
    union select '001;002;123'
) as t2 on 
    t2.id = t1.id
    or t2.id like t1.id + ';%'
    or t2.id like '%;' + t1.id + ';%'
    or t2.id like '%;' + t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the multiple `like` operators is probably the fastest way, but if you have a string splitter function like this one [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), you can split the values out into a table and join to it.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT  * 
                FROM    table2 t2 
                        OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT  *  
                            FROM    dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K] (t2.id,';') -- splits the values in multi id column
                        ) t
                ) t ON  t.Item = t1.id -- t.Item is the value generated from the DelimitedSplit8K TVF
```